# How can I create a text box that uses a python yes/no dialogue text alongside a flask html text box for a website using flask?

Tags: python, flask

New to coding and working on a project using flask but have hit a wall.

I'm trying to create a box that would be in the center of the site screen asking the user the first question. The user would then input yes or no if the input is no it would follow up with the next question until the end of the script.

I don't know Java yet so I wouldn't know how to translate it over and would really like to try if this way if possible. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Also if there is an exact term for this could you please let me know.

The following is the python code I am be using:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session, flash
from datetime import timedelta
import sqlalchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "tops"
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)


@app.route("/home")
def home():
    yes = "yes"
    no = 'no'

questions = ['Could I please have a cookie?',
             'please?',
             'just one?',
             'what if i never ask for another cookie again?\n.......until tomorrow\n'
             'last chance'
             ]

yeses = ["sure, here you go.",
         "ok but just half.",
         "ok sure, but after dinner.",
         "sure, might have one too.",
         "why not, it's been a day"]

nos = ['no way',
       "not today honey",
       "no, you'll spoil your dinner.",
       "you had 2 yesterday, not today hun",
       "we're all out, we'll get some at the store later"
       ]

for i, question in enumerate(questions):
  while True:
    # loop until they respond with yes or no
    answer = input(question).lower()
    if answer != yes and answer != no:
      print('answer yes or no please')
      continue  # continue while loop since wasn't yes/no
    break       # discontinue while loop

  if answer == yes:
    print(yeses[i])  # output i-th yes response
    break
  else:
    print(nos[i])    # output i-th no response
else:
  print("Sorry, you don't get a cookie")
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to build an HTML/JS frontend for your flask server. Python can't be run on a webpage. Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  In general, "I don't know how to write this block of code" is not focused enough for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @TankorSmash Are you saying I wouldn't be able to insert the python text into the website?

Comment: @Prune sure. Will try and make it better on the next one.

Comment: @Prune I've edited the post. Does that clearly explain the problem? Do you know how to help me at this point?

Comment: Yup.  It's still "I don't know how to write this", but I think you're within reasonable bounds now.  I've removed my closure and down votes ... and I hope that some Flask wonk finds the question.  You're beyond what I remember from my one workshop.

Comment: What I meant is that you can only pass text (HTML/CSS and Javascript, basically) to the browser, you can return some data from the server to the page, but you wouldn't be able to write like a Win32 window on the server and display it on the page.